# How to switch pid between python script and subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am launching an application using subprocess and then I analyze the output using a Python script. This Python script is executed by a third-party software which I have no control over. The third-party software measures CPU usage and it measures the CPU usage from the Python script, not the application I am launching via subprocess, which is what I actually need.

It turns out that if I would have launched the application using e.g. bash's `exec` instead of `subprocess`, the PID of the Python script would be the same as of the application, and the application's CPU usage will be measured (which is what I want). However, then I won't be able to analyze the output.

How can I be able to analyze the application's output AND make the third party software measure the CPU usage of the application (and not the Python script)?
I am thinking I have to somehow switch the PID between the Python script and the subprocess. Can this be done?
Any other ideas to solve this problem?

This is on both CentOS 6 and Windows 7 with Python 2.7.

This is what I have so far:

```
import sys, os, subprocess

# Command
command = [Render, '/path/to/file']

# Launch subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen( command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT )

# PIDs
script_pid = os.getpid()
app_pid = p.pid

# Analyze the app's output
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

Comment: You probably can't tackle it like this (process ids aren't switchable on most operating systems). However if you say what the external tool you're using is, or what analysis output you need, then someone may be able to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply redirect `stdout` to something when `exec`ing the other process:

```
import io
import sys

sys.stdout = io.StringIO()   # or BytesIO

exec the_command

output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

---

By the way, your usage of `iter` is useless. Doing:

```
for line in iter(file_object.readline, ''):
```

is *exactly* the same as:

```
for line in file_object:
```

except that:

- It is less readable
- It is longer
- It adds overhead because you are performing a comparison for every line.

You should use `iter(callable, sentinel)` when you want a different kind of iteration.
For example reading the file in chunks of `n` bytes:

```
for chunk in iter(lambda: file_object.read(n), ''):
```

I believe the documentation uses the crappy `iter(f.readline, '')` example because it predates the iterable support for files, so, *at the time*, that was the best way to read a file line by line.